# Youtube data API v3, unable to create certificates or upload videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create playlists and upload videos using Youtube API. I am doing this using a Brand channel's delegated manager account. Which permissions do I need to use? I have tried all of the existing scopes, whichever I could at least.

[image: Youtube Data Api Scopes]

Could anyone let me know if it is even possible to manage playlists and videos through API as a manager of a brand account? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are using the correct scope. What error are you encountering?

Comment: I don't remember existing error as I have to do this from someone else's computer. But It was saying something about not being authorized.